# Android - Changing Activity content when using Tab Host

Tags: android

I am very new to Android, my first app is so far a very simple Tab Host with an Activity for each Tab. My question is what is the best way to manage the Views I display within each Activity?

For example, the first tab loads an activity with four buttons, when a button is pressed I setContentView() to change the content.  However the next time I navigate to this activity it still displays the second view and not the original that is loaded when the onCreate runs (the menu).

As far as I can see OnCreate, and OnStart run only once, the first time you navigate to a activity.  I have also put Logs in to see if onDestroy or onPause ever run when chaning between tabs and it seems they dont run either.  I'm probably doing something stupid, but I can't seem to find the right approach to this!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused. I don't really understand if you switch to another activity upon clicking on a tab or not.

People with a web development background somehow tend to think that they have to set another layout when they switch to another "activity". Now I have quoted activity because apparently those peoples view on what an activity is is flawed.

An activity is not just the layout. It is the actual working application or parts of an application.

So to answer your question. You are not supposed to set another layout using `setContentView()` if you want to switch to another part of your application. You really have to build another activity (as a class I mean) and then set the layout for this activity and the working logic in its class where it belongs.

Just bind an Intent to your button click event or to your tab click event as supposed.

Comment: At present each of my tab's are associated with there own Activity.  I was then going to use each Activity as the controller for everything that is displayed under that tab.  I tried using an new intent to load a new activity, however the new activity would display its view over the top of the Tab view. I also noticed that a lot of people say that you shouldn't use Activities! If thats the case does anyone know how you would then control the views.

Comment: I don't know any experienced developer who would suggest that you should not use Activities but if you are in doubt then I would recommend you buying a good Android book and reading about this stuff a bit.